# DAX query for tables not directly related

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I've 4 tables, all in relations one to many. Table1(one) to (many)Table2(one) to (many)Table3 etc.

I need to sum data in column value from Table4 for every record in Table1.

Table1 and Table4 are not directly related.

Any ideas?

I'm new to DAX and can't find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provided I assume that you have a chain of relationships :

> **Table1 -> Table2 -> Table3 -> Table4**

```
SumValueForTable1Record = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Table4,
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE(Table2),
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        RELATEDTABLE(Table3),
                        Table3[Table3ForeignKeyToTable4] = Table4[Table4PrimaryKey]
                    )
                ) > 0
            )
        ) > 0
    ),
    Table4[value]
)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you Amira.
Now it's little cleaner for me.

Comment: @Zamash please don't forget to validate the answer

Comment: I've tried to also filter that to count only values when in Table 4 other column has value of "post". I added that statement after first, second filter and also added new filter in last the last filter like that && FILTER(Table4, Table4[Column2] = "post") and && COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table4, Table4[Column2] = "post") > 0) but no results...

Comment: That is another issue. My point here does my question answers to the question you posted? If your comment is about another issue than open a new question

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77033831/how-to-add-new-filter-to-a-dax-query

Comment: Validate this one then :)