# How to add new filter to a DAX query

Tags: powerbi, data-science, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I've that query for my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77030269/dax-query-for-tables-not-directly-related) and I'm trying to show records if Table4 name =
"post";

I've tried to make it work like that:

```
var posts = 
    FILTER(
    Table4, 
    Table4[name] = "post"
)

return SUMX(
    FILTER(
        posts,
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE(Table2),
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        RELATEDTABLE(Table3),
                        Table3[table3Id] = Table4[table4Id] 
                    )
                ) > 0
            )
        ) > 0
    ), Table4[value])
```

And by adding && in filters that already are here like that:

```
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Table4,
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE(Table2),
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        RELATEDTABLE(Table3),
                        Table3[table3Id] = Table4[table3Id] 
                    )
                ) > 0
            )
        ) > 0  && Table4[name]="post"
    ), Table4[value])
```

But nothing works. I get blank table..

Comment: In the formula you've shown, you're trying to add a condition Metrics[name] = "post". However, I don't see any table named Metrics from the description you've provided. If this is a table or column that exists in your dataset, make sure that it's appropriately related to the other tables in the model. DAX evaluates within a context, so if Metrics isn't related, then the condition might not apply as you'd expect.

Comment: Also you've used Table3[table3Id] = Table4[table4Id] as a filter condition. But these might not be the correct primary and foreign key relations. Ensure that table3Id in Table3 actually relates to table4Id in Table4.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when writing this. It should be Table4[name] and Table3[table3Id] = Table4[table3Id]. Without that post filter it work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
SumValueForTable1Record = 
VAR ValidTable4 =
    FILTER(
        Table4,
        Table4[name] = "post"
    )

VAR ValidRecords =
    FILTER(
        ValidTable4,
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE(Table2),
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        RELATEDTABLE(Table3),
                        Table3[table3Id] = EARLIER(Table4[table4Id])
                    )
                ) > 0
            )
        ) > 0
    )

RETURN
SUMX(ValidRecords, Table4[value])
```